# Memory leak due to running tf.contrib.image.sparse_image_warp using session

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing

I have a function to warp some face images using their destination landmarks. But I noticed I have a memory leak over time and I checked it using memory_profiler. Here's the code:

```
def image_warping(src_img, src_landmarks, dest_landmarks):
    expanded_src_landmarks = np.expand_dims(np.float32(src_landmarks), axis=0)
    expanded_dest_landmarks = np.expand_dims(np.float32(dest_landmarks), axis=0)
    expanded_src_img = np.expand_dims(np.float32(src_img) / 255, axis=0)

    warped_img, dense_flows = sparse_image_warp.sparse_image_warp(expanded_src_img,
                          expanded_src_landmarks,
                          expanded_dest_landmarks,
                          interpolation_order=1,
                          regularization_weight=0.1,
                          num_boundary_points=2,
                          name='sparse_image_warp')

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        out_img = sess.run(warped_img)
        warp_img = np.uint8(out_img[0, :, :, :] * 255)
    session.close()
    return warp_img
```

memory_profiler shows  466.645 MiB and 174.574 MiB increments for `with tf.Session() as sess:` and `out_img = sess.run(warped_img)` lines, respectively.

Is there any other ways to convert warped_img from tensor to a numpy array rather than running by session? The results of this tf function is much better than any other available image warping codes but I wonder why it returns a tensor as the inputs are all numpy arrays. I'm not using this function in a deep learning algorithm.